# Vue JS How do I not include records which are out of date in page count results

Tags: vue.js

I am trying to work out the logic for displaying only data which has a date after today's date in my page count ie. displays 25 records

I need to be able to display them if the 'show Closed' check box is selected though. This shows the out-of-date records and add them to the 'count' if the box is checked

I pull the records just now and hide them using css, but then the 'returning X records' does not correspond with the records on the page. Can anyone help, please?

Comment: Please attach your code, show us what have you tried.

Comment: I have used moment and then css to hide the 'closed' entires. This does not change the results returned data. I would just like some pointers as to how to go about this if possible.

Comment: Shouldn't you be able to just return the not out of date records from your backend?

Comment: Im unsure how to go about this though. I'm new to Vue. I know how to hide it using css but cant seem to figure how to not display. Maybe its easy but, some pointer would be good if poss. thanks

Comment: No, what I mean is how do you get your data? Is it by hardcoding it to your vue app, or do you get it from an API somewhere?

Comment: Yes, the data is pulled in using Axios. It includes a deadline date as part of the data.
For example:  "T": "1 August 2020",

Answer (score 0):

I think, something like this should answer your problem. You can use computed properties to only return the data you want (before or after your deadline).

```js
<template>
  <div v-for="data in filteredData" :key="data.created_at">
    <p>{{ data.title }} - {{ data.created_at }}</p>
  </div>
  <p>Total Count: {{ filteredData.length }}</p>
  <button @click="showBefore8May = !showBefore8May">
    {{ showBefore8May ? "hide" : "show" }} before 8 May 2021
  </button>
</template>

<script>
import { computed, ref } from "vue";
export default {
  setup() {
    const datas = [
      {
        title: "hello",
        created_at: "2021-05-03 14:01:47",
      },
      {
        title: "hello 2",
        created_at: "2021-05-05 14:01:47",
      },
      {
        title: "hello 3",
        created_at: "2021-05-07 14:01:47",
      },
      {
        title: "hello 4",
        created_at: "2021-05-10 14:01:47",
      },
      {
        title: "hello 5",
        created_at: "2021-05-11 14:01:47",
      },
    ];

    const showBefore8May = ref(true);

    const filteredData = computed(() => {
      return datas.filter((data) => {
        if (!showBefore8May.value) {
          return data.created_at > "2021-05-08 14:01:47";
        }
        return data;
      });
    });

    return { datas, filteredData, showBefore8May };
  },
};
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you! Much appreciated. I will try this out.:)

Comment: Happy to help! Please mark the answer as correct and upvote if you found this answer useful.

Comment: Sorry, im getting an error:  Vue warn]: Property or method "filteredData" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render.

Comment: Are you sure there is no typo?

Comment: Yes, I copied and pasted it again and it stills seems to be the same. Maybe something else in my set up is causing the issue.. I did have to wrap an extra div around the divs too.

Comment: Are you using vue 2?